# only main Subdomain redirect to main domain through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to redirect only main subdomain like 
http://dl.domain.com to domain.com

but not redirect files or script links to main domain.

http://dl.domain.com/123.zip
http://dl.domain.com/zippy.zip etc

How I can do this with .htaccess rules?

I use these .htaccess rules but problem not solve

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^xyz\.php($|/) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```